# get handle of a child control?

Tags: c#, windows

Ciao, I would like to get handle of an combo box that is located on a dialog ? I can only get the Dialog handle but `EnumWindows` doesn't return the expected handle of the combobox. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

EnumWindows only enumerates the Top level windows, in order to get to the child windows you could PInvoke [EnumChildWindows](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html)(pinvoke.net),
or according to this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/70215/Need-examples-of-finding-child-window-through-p-in.aspx) using [FindWindowEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html)(pinvoke.net) should also work.